# Puppeteer - get parent element

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I'm trying to click on one value (odds) based on the name of the other element but those two need to be inside a specific parent element which I get by the text inside it.

The snippet below can be found multiple times on the same page with the same classes so targeting by class is not an option.

I first need to get a container with text "1st Goal. Then I need to get it's parent and in the parent, I need to get the second div element (class parent2). That element holds other elements. Let's imagine I need to get the element of value 200 and click on it.

I've tried using parentElement, parentNode but always get the 'undefiend' when getting a parent of the child element, although the child element is retrieved successfully. I just can't get the parent from where I could go down the tree to the desired element and click on it.

```
<div class="group ">
    <div class="parent1 "><span>1st Goal</span></div>
    <div class="parent2">
        <div class="container ">
            <div">
                <div><span>Malaga</span><span class="odds">200</span></div>
                <div><span>No 1st Goal</span><span class="odds">300</span></div>
                <div><span>Las Palmas</span><span class="gll-odds">400</span></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you try running your selector in the Chrome DevConsole to see if it works outside puppeteer?

Comment: @Cristy Yes I did, in Chrome it works.

Comment: Can you post the code that you tried to execute in `puppeteer`?

Comment: You said "in Chrome it works"...but you might try actually running `puppeteer` in non-headless mode. In your [jest-puppeteer.config.js file](https://github.com/smooth-code/jest-puppeteer#configure-puppeteer), you can set `headless:false` and `devtools: true`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### XPath expressions

If you are okay with using [XPath](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath) expression, you can use the following statement:

```
//div[contains(@class, "group") and contains(., "1st Goal")]/div[@class="parent2"]//span[@class="odds"]
```

This XPath expression queries for a `div` element having the class `group` and containing the text *1st Goal* somewhere. Then it will query the children `div` with the class `parent2` and query `span` elements with class `odds` inside.

#### Usage within puppeteer

To get the element with puppeteer, use the [`page.$x`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.19.0/docs/api.md#pagexexpression) function. To click the element, use [`elementHandle.click`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.19.0/docs/api.md#elementhandleclickoptions).

Putting all together, the code looks like this:

```js
const [targetElement] = await page.$x('//div[contains(@class, "group") and contains(., "1st Goal")]/div[@class="parent2"]//span[@class="odds"]');
await targetElement.click();
```

Answer (score 9):

```
const parent_node = await child_node.getProperty('parentNode')
```

You can try this one